# parallel programming in .net 4.0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing

I have been reading up on the parallel programming and even now still a little confused on the whole concepts. Lets say I have a single project with about 5 classes that interact and have local variables in methods and variables accessible to all methods in a single class and even 1 or 2 variables accessible to all classes accessed through instantiation.
Now using threads I know that global variables would be overridden by multiple threads if there were no locking applied but local variables to a method/function do not, right?
So if I ran the project multiple times meaning as a new process, the methods and variables would be thread safe right and no data corruption occurs?
So to implement parallel programming using the task factory, if I created a project that basically creates tasks and each task is basically running an instance of another project, then shouldn't the variables and data be thread safe and safe from corruption?
But what if I had the output files and they named by Output & datetime.now.tostring, would there be conflict issues and I ask this knowing that I have seen this happen when trying it.

```
dim factory as new taskfactory
factory.startnew(addressof projectinstance.main)
```

Now this maybe common sense for most of you so be gentle on the criticism here please. thanks appreciate any response.

EDIT:

This is the file creation module in one of the classes :

```
Private Sub createXML()
    num += 1
    Dim fileList As New ArrayList
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim file As String = Module1.infile
    xmlfile = directoryPath & "\Feed" & DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") & endExtension
    fileList.Add(xmlfile)
    Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
    xwriter = New XmlTextWriter(xmlfile, Encoding.UTF8)
    xwriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    xwriter.Indentation = 2
    xwriter.WriteStartDocument(True)
    xwriter.WriteStartElement("Posts")
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To gXmlList.Count() - 1
        j += 1
        parseXML(gXmlList(i))
```

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the single program multiple data [SPMD pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPMD). You essentially create a separate program or object graph for each task (a task ulitmately gets scheduled on a thread). Variable instances that are global to the object graph will be fine (so no static globals) but to still need to worry about shared resources like files.

One way to resolve these types of issues is to assign each task instance a unique ID, or "rank", and have it use this to identify resources and name them. In your file example each task would output a file called myoutput_{rank}.txt. If what you actually want is one file then your application has to implement a post processing, aggregation phase where it merges results. This happens sequentially *after* parallelism has ended. This like a map/reduce. Each of your parallel tasks runs the same "program" to map some input data onto an output data set (a file in your case) and then in a separate step your reduce or aggregate the results into the final answer.

Here's an example:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        const int maxJobs = 10;

        // Run jobs and wait...
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int rank = 0; rank < maxJobs; rank++)
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((r) => { new MyApp().Main((int)r); }, rank));

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        // Aggregate results...
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int rank = 0; rank < maxJobs; rank++)
            sb.AppendLine(File.ReadAllText("results_" + rank + ".txt"));

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        File.WriteAllText("results_final.txt", sb.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class MyApp
    {
        public void Main(int rank)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting {0}", rank);
            File.WriteAllText("results_" + rank + ".txt", "result data " + rank);
        }
    }
```

The class MyApp can have as much state as it likes. It can even share that state with child objects but it must not have static state or share state with globals that are read/write defined outside of MyApp.

It is OK to have read only global state. For example all of the MyApp instances could read input data from a single file. What's not OK is to have multiple instances of MyApp reading *and* writing to a (single) global variable, object instance or other resource like a file without implementing some form of coordination (like a lock).

In the example above each task creates a local results_{rank}.txt file. The contents of these are combined into a single result file, results_final.txt, in a separate aggregation step. It's not possible to do this in parallel because then all tasks would be writing to a single global resource.

A lot of these concepts are covered in the book and samples you can find here. The content is also available (for free) on MSDN.

http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks for your response, really appreciate it....globals defined in MyApp would include my output files I am generating so technically then it would be ok...because each task takes an input file and used that inputfile to create a corresponding output file. Is this right?

Comment: I updated my answer. The results_{rank}.txt files are not global, they are local to each Task. If you wanted a single results.txt file then that would be considered global state. Note that global readonly state is OK. Global write or read/write is not.